# apt-offline: command not found

Tags: apt, raspberrypi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi that is not connected to the Internet and a laptop that is. I'm trying to download vim on the Internet connected laptop and then transfer the files with a thumbdrive and install vim on the RPi. One common strategy involves using the `apt-offline` command, but when I try this I get the error message

```
bash: apt-offline: command not found
```

Is there anything I can do in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, `apt-offline` is not part of a default installation.  You would need to manually download `apt-offline` packages to install on the offline Pi, in order to comply with the 'guides' and 'strategies' you mention (but don't reference us to).

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Linux (as you could probably tell) and it didn't occur to me that I could just download an apt-offline package. However, know that I have downloaded apt-offline and have entered sudo apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig as instructed to by this guide https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT I am given the error message "ERROR: FATAL: Something is wrong with the apt system." Is there any way around this error?

Comment: I realized that I had dependency issues, so I downloaded all the packages that apt-offline needed.

Comment: @nkr Does it mean your problem is resolved? If not, please [edit] your question to add details.